# How to search a string in web page and print that full line in which search string is present?

Tags: perl

I'm new to programming, learning perl as well.

Here's my question: How do I search a string in web page and print that full line in which search string is present?

Is it possible to find/hit directly that string and then print that full line in which search string is present? Do we need to use xpaths compulsory for this?

Answer (score 5):

If it is just a very basic string you are looking for you can use [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aSimple) and a small regular expression like this:

```
use LWP::Simple;

my $doc = get('http://stackoverflow.com/q/11771655/479133') || die "GET failed";
foreach my $line (split("\n", $doc)) {
    print $line and last if $line =~ m/Here's my query/;
}
```

There are countless modules available on CPAN to do such things. Have a look at [Task::Kensho::WebCrawling](https://metacpan.org/module/Task%3a%3aKensho#Web-Crawling%3a-Task%3a%3aKensho%3a%3aWebCrawling) if you need something "bigger".

Answer (score 5):

[`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) and [`HTML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aParser) can be used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Parser;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get('http://search.cpan.org/');
if ( !$response->is_success ) {
    print "No matches\n";
    exit 1;
}

my $parser = HTML::Parser->new( 'text_h' => [ \&text_handler, 'dtext' ] );
$parser->parse( $response->decoded_content );

sub text_handler {
    chomp( my $text = shift );

    if ( $text =~ /language/i ) {
        print "Matched: $text\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be over-complicating this. Whilst you'd definitely usually use an HTML parser to process HTML, in this case the question asked for the "full line in which search string is present". In which case, the correct answer is to just split the input on newlines and search the individual lines.